# Javascript Ping by Downloading JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm trying to download a JSON file through  javascript to use in a ping test but the browser appears to be interpreting it as javascript and gives parse errors. here is the code:

```
function sprawdz(adres)
    {
     //ping = 0;                            
     startTime = new Date().getTime( );

     $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       //url: 'http://'+adres+'/img/loading.gif',
       url: 'URL TO JSON FILE HERE',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       async: false,
       setup: function() {
        //
       },
       complete: function(xhr, text)
       {
        //alert(xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.responseText + ' - ' + xhr.status);
        finishTime = new Date( ).getTime( );   
        ping = finishTime - startTime;
        //pngud(ping);
       }
      }
     );
     //return ping + ' ms';
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the exact location of the error and the error message.

Comment: http://i55.tinypic.com/r/dzcacz/7

Comment: @Pekka: technically, that picture _does_ provide exactly what you asked.

Comment: @Matt that wasn't there when I posted the comment. If now we could have the translated line numbers... :)

Comment: @Pekka: yup, I know. `head ===> desk`

Comment: Did you get anything to show up in the console with my code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a `dataType` of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP). JSONP **is** JavaScript.

Did you mean `dataType: 'json'`?

---

Let's try to get a better idea of what the server is actually sending to you. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/json/ping',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

What shows up in the console?

Comment: @William I appreciate the effort of your screen shot, but we need to know the exact line the error appears in. It's impossible to tell from the image.

Comment: @William: what happened when you used `dataType: 'json'`? What data does the server actually send back? To elaborate on Pekka's comment - a line number isn't useful if we can't see _what code is on that line._

Comment: It returns what is in the image posted above.

Comment: @William: I assure you, that is **not** what the server sends back. Those are the HTTP request headers (which is part of what the _browser_ sends to the _server_) and some JavaScript error messages. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

its interpreted as json and should be a valid json string then.
however what on earth is your definition of "ping"?